How can we get our dApp to not have the malicious error
My dapp showing malicious warning error everytime am buying the token..how to resolve this blowfish not provide any valid solution...kindly assist me

This question is similar to: How to resolve the issue of Phantom wallet wrongly prompting phishing alerts for website transaction signatures?. Flagging this for closure.

Also I have the same problem. I'm new in solana community and blowfish want to known person reach out to their

Most wallets, backpack and phantom use Blowfish to flag malicious and suspicious transactions.
You will need to contact them to tell them to whitelist your dApp domain through their email review@blowfish.xyz

blowfish not reply my question in twitter and email
